# PermGen Space almost overflow. Using jboss 4.2.2GA

Tags: jboss, jboss-4.2.x

I've got OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space, and i'm trying many times to change it under run.conf under jboss/bin/run.conf but still i can't see any changes after restart jboss
im using Jboss 4.2.2GA
         OS: Linux centos
         jvm: 1.5.2 hotspot server 64bit

please, any suggestion..

```
Heap Configuration:
   MinHeapFreeRatio = 40
   MaxHeapFreeRatio = 70
   MaxHeapSize      = 1073741824 (1024.0MB)
   NewSize          = 2686976 (2.5625MB)
   MaxNewSize       = -65536 (-0.0625MB)
   OldSize          = 1835008 (1.75MB)
   NewRatio         = 2
   SurvivorRatio    = 8
   PermSize         = 21757952 (20.75MB)
   MaxPermSize      = 88080384 (84.0MB)

Heap Usage:
PS Young Generation
Eden Space:
   capacity = 332922880 (317.5MB)
   used     = 39076184 (37.265953063964844MB)
   free     = 293846696 (280.23404693603516MB)
   11.73730805164247% used
From Space:
   capacity = 12582912 (12.0MB)
   used     = 0 (0.0MB)
   free     = 12582912 (12.0MB)
   0.0% used
To Space:
   capacity = 12386304 (11.8125MB)
   used     = 0 (0.0MB)
   free     = 12386304 (11.8125MB)
   0.0% used
PS Old Generation
   capacity = 691994624 (659.9375MB)
   used     = 159954680 (152.54467010498047MB)
   free     = 532039944 (507.39282989501953MB)
   23.115017725918054% used
PS Perm Generation
   capacity = 76742656 (73.1875MB)
   used     = 75870592 (72.3558349609375MB)
   free     = 872064 (0.8316650390625MB)
   98.8636515264731% used
```

Comment: is it good idea to add JAVA_OPTS to environment variables.., but i'm still confused how Jboss didn't work on run.conf?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if you have `run.conf` file in the your configuration directory (`default` or maybe `production`).

At least in JBoss EAP 4.3 each profile can have own running configuration file. If you find such file you have to edit `-XX:MaxPermSize` parameter.

Comment: i'm editing run.conf in the bin directory...and i checked all the conf directories, i don't have run.conf

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure your JBoss instance is properly configured to handle PermGen.  I don't know why the default configs don't come with this stuff in them; for some reason you need to just ***magically*** know this stuff.  Here's a link on how to configure: http://blog.dahanne.net/2009/08/12/jboss-and-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-permgen-space/.